# How to handle stolen check with unhelpful issuer

Tags: united-states, check

Someone stole a check from me and received my money. The check was from a large company, and they aren't interested in assisting me in resolving the issue. I don't know who stole the check.

1. Is there a way to figure out who cashed the check without the assistance of the company which issued the check? Can the police do this easily?
2. Is the company under any obligation to assist me with this problem?
3. Am I right in assuming that the company which issued the check can easily call their bank and figure out who deposited it? Will this work even if the check was cashed instead of deposited?

While I'd like the money, my primary goal is to figure out who got the money so I don't get stolen from again.

Comment: For clarity, are you seeking help in obtaining a repeat payment from the company ?

Answer (score 3):

I would call the police and file a report. Then I will notify the issuer in writing and ask for the check to be re-issued. Make sure you include the police report number. How they deal with it is their problem, not yours. You did not get the money, therefore they still own it to you.

Comment: I'm not sure the last part holds up, feel like if I give someone a check I have paid them. If I paid you cash and it was then stolen from you, don't think I am on the hook .

Comment: @HartCO Cash is a legal tender, checks are not. When the money from the check is deposited in my account, then the debt is extinguished, not before.

Comment: That's why giving the police report number to the company is important: they company sees that the check was cashed, and you need something to back up your assertion that someone *else* did so without your consent.

Comment: @HartCO: In case of loss (which includes theft) the writer of the check should be off the hook for any sort of late penalties or accrued interest for a delayed payment, but they still need to make good on the original amount.

Comment: "Contact your bank or credit union right away. State law generally provides that you are not responsible for a check if someone forged the signature of the person to whom you made out the check." - https://www.consumerfinance.gov/ask-cfpb/i-wrote-a-check-to-someone-but-it-was-stolen-the-thief-forged-the-indorsement-on-the-check-and-then-cashed-it-my-bankcredit-union-deducted-the-money-from-my-account-what-can-i-do-en-991/   This makes sense to me, the bank that accepted the forgery should be the liable party.

Comment: That's assuming it was even forged, if it was endorsed by OP and then left lying around, it is certainly not the issuer's responsibility to double-pay. If that were the case, you could sell your endorsed checks and get double-paid on every check.

Comment: @HartCO: That's why you first write the account number to deposit into, then sign underneath, so the check can never be treated as an unrestricted endorsement.  Strangely, most tutorials I've seen get this wrong.

Comment: @HartCO My understanding is that's not true according to the law. [UCC 3-309](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-309) says you are still entitled payment if the check is lost, stolen, or destroyed. The issuer can pursue a claim with the fact that the stolen check was wrongfully paid against the bank. A check is not cash, it is an instruction for the bank to pay. As ventsyv alluded to, [UCC 3-310](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-310) says giving somebody a check merely suspends the obligation to pay until payment actually occurs (or the check is dishonored).

Comment: @user71659 I saw discussions that referenced UCC 3-310(b)(4) in support of the notion that the obligation cannot be enforced, but I didn't spend too much time on it.. The issue with checks is that they can be legally transferred, I can accept it as payment, sign it over to another party as payment to them, and they can deposit it legally. I don't think in any case the issuer is liable, and unless the check was forged I don't think the issuers bank  is liable either. If OP endorsed and lost the check, that's on them.

Comment: @HartCO The first bank who accepted the item with the forged endorsement [is ultimately liable](https://www.bankersonline.com/qa/drawee-bank-liability-forged-endorsements), e.g. the check cashing place used by the criminal. I don't see why you think endorsements matter, if the check was stolen before the recipient got it, somebody could easily scrawl something on the back. As the link says, subsequent banks have no responsibility to check endorsements. The drawee has no idea what the signature should be. Ultimately it's clear, the UCC says the OP is not liable.

Comment: @user71659 My point about endorsement is that, as your link suggests, the bank that accepted the forged item is liable. If no forgery took place because the OP endorsed it over to another party, then clearly the issuer should not make a duplicate payment.

Comment: @HartCO Your last statement is obvious but unrelated to the question: if no crime occurs, they shouldn't pay twice. But basically your original assumption is incorrect: in no case does the person to whom the check was issued to lose the money due to loss or fraud of the check. The person who wrote the check needs to reissue a new one as many times as necessary because their liability does not go away until the OP is properly paid. If their bank did pay out on fraudulent activity, they need to pursue a claim against their bank who will then make claims against other banks.

Comment: @user71659 I disagree with your assessment. Issuers are afforded protections too, and in some cases the recipient could lose money (maybe only limited to instances where they were negligent in their handling of the instrument). See UCC 3-309(b) and UCC 3-406. In general it seems like the issuer would be obligated to re-issue payment if not put at risk of double-paying and so long as the need for re-issuing was not brought about by recipient's negligence. Think this comment thread is long enough, so I'll be done with it, but will definitely read any additional bits you share.